# URL for thumbnail in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Trying to add a JS data attribute to a Wordpress thumbnail. I need the absolute URL of the image, not the post it's attached to.

Got this far:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-full', array('class' => 'addthis_shareable', 'addthis:url' => $src)); ?>
```

I thouhgt from the docs that `$src` would hold the URL, but it doesn't. All I get in the code is `addthis:url` at the end of the image tag, but no URL with it.

Any help? PHP is not my thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail-full');
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-full', array(
  'class' => 'addthis_shareable',
  'addthis:url' => $src
));?>
```

Comment: Here's what I got with that, which is just bizarre: `<img width="2000" height="1382" src=...snip... class="addthis_shareable wp-post-image" alt="star-trek-into-darkness-zachary-quinto-chris-pine1" addthis:url="Array">`

I guess the function is returning an Array to the variable?

Comment: Okay, I used `wp_get_attachment_url` in place of `wp_get_attachment_image_src` and it's working. Thanks!